# куда вставить якорь в пагинацию

Tags: php, pagination

Пагинатор воспринимает из базы записи. Как сделать, чтобы после занесения в базу последней записи можно было посмотреть сразу результат, а не клацать последнюю страницу. Думаю, что параметром GET по последней дате:

```
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0; index.php?date=$date'>";
```

А вот на index-странице куда вставить якорь в пагинацию не знаю. Подскажите. 
[image: якорь в таблице]

[image: якорь в ссылке]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А не проще в запросе прописать `ORDER BY id DESC`? И данные вернуться в обратном порядке, что позволит последним данным быть вверху страницы.

Comment: пробовал, не идет   сюда вставить users LIMIT ".$limit_start.",".$limit); как именно

Comment: Ну так вы и не добавили попробуйте вот так `SELECT *  FROM user ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT " . $limit_start . ", " . $limit` Да и при использовании двойных кавычек переменные будут прочтены корректно.

Comment: Вставил сюда users  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ".$limit_start.",".$limit); спасибо